# Integrating AWS AppSync (+ Cognito) Schema with Graphene django on lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, graphene-python, aws-appsync

I've an AWS AppSync GraphQL endpoint with some DynamoDB tables and it is integrated with Cognito.

I've also developed a django application with graphql endpoint (graphene) and cognito integration that is deployed with zappa to a lambda function.

What is the best way to combine those two graphql endpoints, so that i can query them from one endpoint?
1- Appsync forwards requests to lambda with resolvers? (any examples?)
2- Intercept calls from api gateway and forward them to appsync? (less likely)

Thanks,
Alp

Comment: Option 1 sounds better to me because 1/ you're using native AWS AppSync capabilities 2/ no additional latency by jumping thru another service

Comment: Yep, i'm also thinking that would be the best, but couldn't find any good example of appsync forwarding requests to another graphql endpoint.

Comment: Instead of forwarding requests, can you reuse that Lambda function as an AppSync resolver?

Comment: What did you end up doing?

Comment: @ox. well i ended up removing AppSync from the equation and running graphql queries through graphene graphql endpoint.

Comment: @AlpGüneysel cool, still using zappa?

Comment: @ox. yes, django webapp integrated with amazon cognito user pools, amazon rds (postgresql) and using django graphene deployed with zappa to a lambda function.

Comment: @AlpGüneysel Would you mind sharing why you ditched AppSync? Any particular issues, or just reducing complexity more generally?

Comment: Hi @Alp, would you help me to understand how to integrate Cognito in a Django Zappa app?

Comment: @GustavoSooeiro if you're going to need Social Login, don't use Cognito, use Firebase instead. if a normal login is sufficient for you, you'll need to use aws amplify on the client side. https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication

Comment: @AlpGüneysel thank yoy very much for your tip. I would like to understand why you've choosen Firebase instead of Cognito for Social Login. Is it because it is easyer to implement? I do need Social Login, and since Cognito provide that, why not use it to integrate with a Zappa Django app?

Comment: @GustavoSooeiro with cognito, you can't merge users who signed with social login ; a user signed up with username and password, one day later wanted to use facebook to login to his account, you would expect that if the emails are the same, cognito would automatically merge the fields from the social provider to the user. But cognito creates another user in federated identity pool (if i remember the name correctly) and there is no way to merge the users and you will get different tokens and user id's for them. Only if you use their hosted login page, this is possible. I wasted one month on this

Comment: @GustavoSooeiro and firebase automatically merges the users as you would expected.

Comment: @GustavoSooeiro Here is the issue on their github and amazingly they talk about workarounds which do not work. This is an ongoing issue for like 2 years. (first mentioned on aws forums in 2017)  https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/1316

And, with firebase, you can do all that in like 10-15 minutes after you setup their SDK correctly.